# Dynamic adding specific favicon on selection from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

Full code with `+` button which is calling apparance of div block above, and the `<div class="item_socails">` where new `<li>` components must be added :

I have a dropdown like this :

```
<div class="item_socails">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
      <input value="laurie.lowe13" type="text">
    </li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-odnoklassniki"></i>
      <input value="laurie.lowe1997" type="text">
    </li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-vk"></i>
      <input value="laurie.lowe7" type="text">
    </li>
    <li>
      <button id="add_social_top" class="dropdown-button add_social waves-effect waves-blue" type="button"><span>+</span></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="show_social">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Twitter</option>
    <option value="2">LinkedIn</option>
    <option value="3">Facebook</option>
  </select>
  <input class="txt_select" type="text" value="laurie.lowe13">
  <button class="waves-effect waves-blue btn z-depth-1" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>
```

So, basically user is clicking on the `+` button, and this div appears, where user have to select one of social networks, and in input to introduce it's link. On "add" `submit` button I want to generate a new item like

```
<li><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i> <input value="laurie.lowe13" type="text" </li>
```

Basically, a new list item on a specific div, with a favicon of selected social network and an input with introduced value.

How can I achieve it ? Thanks.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt `+` button is above that dropdown. When I click on it, this div appears where I should select a social network and value. After submit, it must be added to a div above. I will edit my code with this button and div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `append()` for adding an element and `:selected` text for the icon.

And if you want to add a `<li>` element, wrap it into `<ul>`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(".btn-add").on("click", function() {
  $(".main").append("<li><i class='fa fa-" + $(".show_social select").find(":selected").text().toLowerCase() + "'></i><input value=" + $(".txt_select").val() + " type='text'</li>")
})
```

```css
.main {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="show_social">
  <select>
    <option value="1">Twitter</option>
    <option value="2">LinkedIn</option>
    <option value="3">Facebook</option>
  </select>
  <input class="txt_select" type="text" value="laurie.lowe13">
  <button class="waves-effect waves-blue btn btn-add z-depth-1" type="submit">Add</button>
  <ul class="main"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Solved

Changed this block :

```
<div class="show_social">
    <select>
        <option value="1">Twitter</option>
        <option value="2">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="3">Facebook</option>
    </select>
    <input class="txt_select" type="text"
           value="laurie.lowe13">
    <button
        class="waves-effect waves-blue btn z-depth-1"
        type="submit">Add
    </button>
</div>
```

with :

```
<div class="show_social">
    <select name="social" id="select_social">
        <option value="fa fa-twitter">Twitter</option>
        <option value="fa fa-linkedin">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="fa fa-odnoklassniki">Ok.ru</option>
        <option value="fa fa-facebook-f">Facebook</option>
        <option value="fa fa-vk">Vk.com</option>
    </select>
    <input class="txt_select" type="text" id="select_input"
           value="laurie.lowe13">
    <button
        class="waves-effect waves-blue btn z-depth-1" id="addSocialNetwork"
        type="button">Добавить
    </button>
</div>
```

Then, in JS :

```
$('#addSocialNetwork').on('click', function() {
    var selectedIcon = $('#select_social').val();
    var selectedInput = $('#select_input').val();
    var template = '<li><i class="' + selectedIcon + '"></i> <input value="' + selectedInput + '" type="text"> </li>'
    $('#existingSocials').append(template);

});
```

> Explanation :

User clicks `+` button, appears a `div` with dropdown of social networks. Each select has value equal with `class` of `fav-icon`. Then, user is introducing a value (link) to his social network.  When he hits `Add button` to confirm. Runs a script that takes value current selected option  that is `class of favicon`, then takes value of input (link) and prepare an entire template, that in next step is appended to existing block.